# How does a Blu-Ray work?

Tags: laser

I've just bought a BluRay, and I want to know how it works. I'm not searching for a high-level scientific explanation--just a simple answer.

Comment: I don't think the question as it is written here belongs here. We don't know from your question whether the answer you want is about the electronics, the file-format, the wavelength of the laser, etc... If you look at wikipedia or the first result of a google search, you can already have some answers. If they're not good enough from you, edit your question and explain why they are not satisfying.

Comment: Technology question, not a physics one.

Comment: suggestion to move this to superuser.com?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/blu-ray2.htm

Comment: Please note that answers that are just links are discouraged--you must give atleast an overview of the phenomenon explained in the link--otherwise your answer is liable to being downvoted.

Comment: @Manisheart just a quick one, do you like run this site or something?

Comment: @Olly: Nope ;). This site is run by virtually nobody--or you could say that the community runs it. I'm just a normal user, who downvote+comment's on bad posts. Others do this as well. Moderators (they have a ♦), and 10k+ rep users do a bit of the behind-the-scenes work. SO staff members (also ♦) could be said to run the site; but they also do so after listening to community input. http://www.codinghorror.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b01538eefee40970b-800wi